# SQL Server Compatibility with older DotNetNuke versions

Tags: sql-server, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to determine whether DNN 2.0.4 will be compatible with SQL Server 2005 SP4. My company is upgrading their server framework and they're trying to determine (without testing obviously...) if the SQL upgrade will blow up some of their older DNN sites.

I've trolled the boards, liberally dusted with Google magic and even skimmed through the super user manual. The nearest I've been able to get to an answer is that the latest version REQUIRES SQL Server 2005 but there's no indication that it will work with the older DNN.

Anybody out there have any concrete experience I can fall back on?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the large installed base and wide variety of environments, the DNN core team has focused on using very standard SQL and I think if there was any problem, your searching would have turned something up.

Also, I'm not aware of any breaking changes or features in SQL Server 2000 that were removed in SQL Server 2005.

You should be fine. If you do run into a problem it's much more likely to be with a 3rd party module rather than the core. Some 3rd party modules were much quicker to begin to use the new capabilities of SQL Server 2005 and in general are less likely to follow standards or be tested as extensively in a wide variety of environments.

Answer (score 0):

I am running 2.1.2 on SQL Server 2005 without issues. I think that the same would be true of 2.0.4.

Comment: Which service pack are you using for SQL 2005?

Comment: Service Pack 2, but after checking I remembered that I have since moved the database to SQL Server 2008. So I was running it on SQL Server 2005 SP2, without issues.

Comment: Thanks for the info (You too EfficionDave). I've passed it up the chain and it looks like they are going to start running some sandbox tests now. We just needed a sanity check.